# javascript - Global variable not working

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a variable that I want saved so that multiple functions can use it. I followed w3schools's directions but it doesn't work. Am I forgetting something? Thank you in advance.

```js
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;

function complete() {
 document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = name;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to consider:

- If you have code that attempts to find an element, but that element hasn't even been read by the browser yet, the browser won't be able to find it. So, make sure that your code only runs AFTER the full DOM has been loaded
  by placing the script just before the closing `body` tag.
- Don't attempt to get the value of a form field as soon as the page
  loads because the user hasn't typed anything into it yet, so the
  `value` will be nothing. You need to set up your code so that your function gets called at the right time (after the user has had a chance to type in the form field) so only get the value when that moment has come.
- Don't give any element the name `name` because the Global `window`
  object has a property called `name` that defaults to an empty string
  and when you attempt to access `name`, it could incorrectly attempt
  to get the `window.name` instead of your element called `name`.
- Only form fields have a value property. All other elements have
  `.textContent` (used when the string does not contain any HTML or you
  want the actual HTML code displayed, rather than parsed) and
  `.innerHTML` (used when the string does contain HTML and you want
  that code parsed).

Lastly, do yourself a favor and don't use W3Schools. It is well known to have outdated or flat out wrong information on it. Instead use the **[Mozilla Developer's Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web)**, which is recognized as one of the best resources for client-side web development documentation.

```html
<input type="text" id="userName">
<input type="button" value="Click Me!" id="btn">
<div id="demo"></div>

<script>
  // Set up the button's click event handling function
  document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", complete);
  
  // Only get a reference to the element, not its value because, at this point,
  // the user hasn't had a chance to type anything into it.
  // Also, getting a reference to the element is the best approach because, if
  // you decide you want some other property of the same element later, you'd have
  // to scan the document for the same element again.
  var theName = document.getElementById('userName');

  function complete() {
   // Now, just get the current value of the textbox at this moment in time
   document.getElementById('demo').textContent = theName.value;
  }
</script>
```